# Xamarin.Forms video streaming library that supports RTSP video feeds

Tags: xamarin, video-streaming, cross-platform, rtsp, rtsp-client

I am using `Plugin.MediaManager` NuGet package to provide cross-platform video player for my app. However, it does not support playing RTSP video streams. Is there any other library that supports this?

I have looked around and the most common ones are platform-specific libraries such as [KXmovie](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie) and [Managed Media Aggregation](https://net7mma.codeplex.com/) but I am a little intimidated by the thought of having to port and/or recompile them.

The best case is if there is a Xamarin.Forms compatible NuGet package available. Failing that, an iOS library that requires binding, but not recompiling. As a last resort, something that needs to be compiled and linking manually, but works out of the box.

Comment: If anyone is downvoting, could they please give a comment explaining why? The close votes are for the reason of 'off topic - doesn't appear to be about programming'. How is this not about programming?

Comment: I agree with you, Hate when people doing that.

Comment: Are you sure it is not supported? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23012/rtsp-streaming-cant-play-this-video.

Comment: @YuriS Hi! From what I can tell the native Android video player supports RTSP but the native iOS video player does not. The article you linked me to is for Xamarin.Android. If you can find one for Xamarin.IOS or Xamarin.Forms I will be a happy guy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so the resounding conclusion is that one does not exist with Xamarin bindings. I will start with [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/iMoreApps/ffmpeg-avplayer-for-ios-tvos) and see if I can compile and generate the bindings myself.

Comment: Hi. Did you succeed with binding the project? Or did you find another way to stream RTSP?

Comment: Yeah, I have the same question :) Do you have any progress?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply all. Yes I solved it in the end. I will have to dig out the code because that was a while back :D. I will get back to you.

Comment: Hi I'm also interested in this topic. Any links to libs or part of source code will be welcome.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but there is now. [LibVLCSharp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp) supports RTSP (and many other stuff).

Comment: Only one disadvantage that it will increase app size ~60mb

Comment: This can be alleviated https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlc-nuget/-/blob/master/cherry-picking.md

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work for android. "There is not such inclusion/exclusion mechanism for Android because libvlc is built as one monolithic library on this platform.". What i did, i excluded X86, x86_64 architectures so size increased "only" ~40mb, instead ~60mb

Comment: then you need to build your own custom libvlc build with just the features you need. We can't provide every single possible build combinations for every platform.

Comment: Relax man. It is not complain. Just small note. Overall VlcSharp is great.